# Issues reading then printing from File I/O with structs

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to read a CSV file and print out select values from said file, all of them strings (with one char at the end) and I'm having trouble actually printing it out. It's supposed to ignore specific data from the input, like `ASO,ORL,PR`, and of course skip over the empty spaces. I don't know if it's a problem with the File I/O or I'm printing it wrong. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>




typedef struct airdata{
    char *siteNum;
    char *LocalID;
    char *portName;
    char *city;
    char *state;
    char *lat;
    char *lon;
    char Tower;
} airdata;

int main(){
    FILE * fin = fopen("florida.csv", "rw");

    if((fin = fopen("florida.csv", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("etl ERROR: File inputFile not found.\n");
        return(0);
    }
    printf("\nFile opened successfully\n\n");
        printf("%-12s %-11s %-42s %-34s %-3s %-15s %-16s Tower\n",
                "FAA Site", "Short Name", "Airport Name", "City", "ST",
                "Latitude", "Longitude");

        printf("%-12s %-11s %-42s %-34s %-3s %-15s %-16s =====\n",
                "========", "==========", "============", "====", "==",
                "========", "=========");

            char buffer[1000];
            while(fscanf(fin, "%s", buffer) != EOF){
                    airdata * entry = malloc(sizeof(airdata));
                    fprintf(fin, "%s%s%s%s%s%*s%*s%*s%s%s%*s%*s%c%*s%*s", entry->siteNum, entry->LocalID,
                            entry->portName, entry->city, entry->state, entry->lat, entry->lon, entry->Tower);
                    printf("%s%s%s%s%s%*s%*s%*s%s%s%*s%*s%c%*s%*s", entry->siteNum, entry->LocalID,
                        entry->portName, entry->city, entry->state, entry->lat, entry->lon, entry->Tower);
        }

        fclose(fin);
}
```

Here's the input and output

```
IN:
03010.1*A,63FD,LINK FIELD,ALACHUA,FL,ASO,ORL,PR,29-41-53.0000N,082-29-29.0000W,PR,,NON-NPIAS,,N,,,2,0

OUT: 
03010.1*A    63FD        LINK FIELD                                 ALACHUA                            FL  29-41-53.0000N  082-29-29.0000W  N
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you open the file twice?

Comment: Points for answer: 1. `fscanf()` should be used to read data, not `fprintf()`. 2. You must allocate buffers for reading strings and save pointers to them  each members of `airdata`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers all! Looking at it now, not at 1 am, I can see lots of mistakes. Going back to the drawing board! (Pablo's answer is great, I just am required to use fscanf)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange, with your posted code you shouldn't be able to write anything in
`fin`, because you opened it for reading only.

```
FILE * fin = fopen("florida.csv", "rw");

if((fin = fopen("florida.csv", "r")) == NULL)
...
```

You opened it once for read/write and the reopen it again using the same `FILE*`
variable, the read/write handle is lost. The `fprintf(fin, ...)` calls should
return -1.

The second problem is:

```
while(fscanf(fin, "%s", buffer) != EOF){
    airdata * entry = malloc(sizeof(airdata));
    fprintf(fin, "%s%s%s%s%s%*s%*s%*s%s%s%*s%*s%c%*s%*s", entry->siteNum, entry->LocalID,
            entry->portName, entry->city, entry->state, entry->lat, entry->lon, entry->Tower);
    printf("%s%s%s%s%s%*s%*s%*s%s%s%*s%*s%c%*s%*s", entry->siteNum, entry->LocalID,
        entry->portName, entry->city, entry->state, entry->lat, entry->lon, entry->Tower);
}
```

You allocate memory for an `airdata` object in every loop, but it is always
uninitialized, so you will get garbage when you print its members. Also `fin` is opened for reading only,
the write operation will fail. You are not freeing the memory either, so you are
leaking memory on ever loop iteration. Lastly you don't check if `malloc`
returns `NULL`.

Note that the `fscanf` call will only get you the next word, not the whole line,
that's it because `%s` matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

The output you've shown us in the question is not possible with your code.

Regardless, you should do the parsing in a different way. Read the whole line
with `fgets` and then use `strtok` to get the values:

```
int main(void)
{
    airdata **entries = NULL, **tmp;
    size_t num_of_entries = 0;
    char buffer[1024];
    const char *delim = ",\r\n";

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fin))
    {
        tmp = realloc(entries, sizeof *entries);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            // one possible error handling
            fclose(fin);
            free_airdata_array(entries, num_of_entries);
            return 1;
        }

        entries = tmp;

        airdata *data = calloc(1, sizeof *data);

        if(data == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fin);
            free_airdata_array(entries, num_of_entries);
            return 1;
        }

        // parsing
        char **params[] = {
            &data->siteNum,
            &data->LocalID,
            &data->portName,
            &data->city,
            &data->state,
            &data->lat,
            &data->lon,
        };

        char *input = buffer, *token;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof params / sizeof *params; ++i)
        {
            token = strtok(input, delim);
            if(token == NULL)
            {
                flcose(fin);
                free_airdata_array(entries, num_of_entries);
                free_airdata(data);
                return 1;
            }

            *params[i] = strdup(token);

            if(*params[i] == NULL)
            {
                flcose(fin);
                free_airdata_array(entries, num_of_entries);
                free_airdata(data);
                return 1;
            }

            input = NULL; // subsequent calls of strtok expect NULL
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(token == NULL)
            data->Tower = 0;
        else
            data->Tower = *token;

        entries[num_of_entries++] = data;
    }

    fclose(fin);
    do_something_with_the(entries, num_of_entries);

    free_airdata_arra(entries);

    return 0;
}
```

And the `free` functions:

```
void free_airdata_array(airdata **array, size_t num_of_entries)
{
    if(array == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_of_entries; ++i)
        free_airdata(array[i]);

    free(array);
}

void free_airdata(airdata *data)
{
    if(data == NULL)
        return;

    char **params[] = {
        &data->siteNum,
        &data->LocalID,
        &data->portName,
        &data->city,
        &data->state,
        &data->lat,
        &data->lon,
    };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof params / sizeof *params; ++i)
        free(*params[i]);

    free(data);
}
```

If your system does not have `strdup`:

```
char *strdup(const char *text)
{
    if(text == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *ret = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    if(ret == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return strcpy(ret, text);
}
```