# How to split up a line in a text file into multiple variables in C

Tags: c

I have an array of structs with the same amount of indexes as lines in the text file, that contains the following variables:

```
char[] model, float version, int price, char[] color;
```

I am reading from a file that has lines where each line fills one struct. Here is an example of a couple lines from the file:

```
F150 5.4 28000 white
RAM1500 5.7 32000 orange
```

So if I'm reading the first line, I want to save F150 in `char[] model`, 5.7 in float version, 28000 in `int price`, and white in `char[] color` all in the struct stored in the first spot of the array.

I am unsure as to how to traverse the text file and assign the different variables to each struct in the array, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current code for the accessing and reading of this file is here:

```
void accessFile(char *fn) {
struct vehicle *array;
int count = 0;
char line[100];
FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "r");
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) {
    count++;
}

array = (struct vehicle *) malloc(count * sizeof(struct vehicle));

rewind(fp);
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) {
    count++;
    }
}
```

I ran through the file the first time to find the lines in the file in order to know how large to create the array. My plan is to assign each line with their corresponding variables in each struct, but I'm struggling with the syntax for how to differentiate between the individual parts of each line.

Comment: So far you haven't wrote any code at all, haven't you tried it? SO is not a coding service, don't expect us to deliver code for you. You have to show that you al least tried.

Comment: According to the example, from the file you are reading strings. So, here is a hint: you need to parse the string and on the way figure out which element you are parsing. Then you need to convert corresponding elements into corresponding data type, i.e. convert ascii "5.4" into float. Good luck.

Comment: @Pablo I added the code, but it's really not going to be a lot of help for answering my question, because it's not that something isn't working, but rather I don't know how to construct the syntax. I never asked for somebody to write the code, as you can read above, i said "any help would be greatly appreciated" so I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction, like Serge has done.

Comment: @DrewPesall don't take the comments personally, but we cannot read minds, I don't know if you've tried something and failed or was just lazy and wanted code from us. Now that you've posted code, we can comment it, point out your error, etc.

Comment: Yesterday I gave an answer to a question that was almost the same as yours, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sscanf() to split the line.

Since I was bored, I did this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
  char* model;
  float version;
  int   price;
  char* color;
}
vehicle;

bool vehicle_create( vehicle* v, const char* model, float version, int price, const char* color )
{
  v->model   = strdup( model );
  if (!(v->model)) return false;

  v->version = version;
  v->price   = price;
  v->color   = strdup( color );  

  if (v->color) return true;

  free( v->model );
  return false;
}

void vehicle_destroy( vehicle* v )
{
  if (!v) return;
  if (v->model) free( v->model ); v->model = NULL;
  if (v->color) free( v->color ); v->color = NULL;
}

bool read_vehicle( FILE* f, vehicle* v )
{
  char  model[ 50 ];
  char  color[ 50 ];
  char  line[ 200 ];
  float version;
  int   price;

  if (!fgets( line, sizeof(line), f )) 
    return false;

  if (4 != sscanf( line, "%50s %f %d %50s", model, &version, &price, color ))
    return false;

  return vehicle_create( v, model, version, price, color );
}

size_t read_vehicle_inventory( FILE* f, vehicle* vs, size_t n )
{
  size_t count = 0;
  while (count < n 
      && read_vehicle( f, vs + count ))
    count += 1;
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  const size_t MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE = 100;
  vehicle inventory[ MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE ];
  size_t inventory_size = 0;

  // Load inventory from file
  inventory_size = read_vehicle_inventory( stdin, inventory, MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE );

  printf( "inventory size = %d\n", (int)inventory_size );

  // Display the inventory
  for (size_t n = 0; n < inventory_size; n++)
    printf( "%s %s %f is $%d\n", 
      inventory[ n ].color,
      inventory[ n ].model,
      inventory[ n ].version,
      inventory[ n ].price );

  // Free inventory
  for (size_t n = 0; n < inventory_size; n++)
    vehicle_destroy( inventory + n );

  return 0;
}
```

Enjoy.