# Clean up a csv file in C

Tags: c, csv, parsing

How can I select certain fields of a CSV file in C? For instance, given the following line:

```
    03010.1*A,63FD,LINK FIELD,ALACHUA,FL,ASO,ORL,PR,29-41-53.0000N,082-29-29.0000W,PR,,NON-NPIAS,,N,,,2,0
```

How could I store every value to a struct, with the exception of ASO, ORL, PR, NON-NPIAS, and the trailing 2,0 at the end of the line?

My struct definition is as follows:

```
typedef struct airPdata
{
char *siteNumber;
char *locID;
char *fieldName;
char *city;
char *state;
char *latitude;
char *longitude;
char *controlTower;
} airPdata;
```

I understand how to use strsep() to remove the commas in between fields, but I'm not sure how to eliminate unneeded fields.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. By the way, using `strsep` is not safe in general because a separator-like symbol may be quoted and _not_ act as a separator. You'd rather use a CSV parser, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115529/parse-csv-file-in-c

Comment: This is almost the same question we had a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696652/issues-reading-then-printing-from-file-i-o-with-structs   I already answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698026/1480131

Comment: If you know to which member of your struct you need to assign a value, how can you possibly not know which value to simply not assign?